# (PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ";") during simple declare cursor statement and loop over select data

Tags: oracle, plsql

Every time when I want to declare simple variable in Oracle SQL, I become `PLS-00103` error..

```sql
DECLARE CURSOR my_data IS
    SELECT ID, NAME
    FROM NAMES
    WHERE NAME IN ('name1', 'name2', 'name3');
BEGIN
  FOR i IN my_data LOOP
         dbms_output.put_line(i.ID);
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Error which I become:

```
[Code: 6550, SQL State: 65000]  ORA-06550: Zeile 4, Spalte 45:
PLS-00103: Fand das Symbol "end-of-file" als eines der folgenden erwartet wurde:
;
[Script position: 116 - 117]    
DECLARE CURSOR my_data IS
    SELECT ID, NAME
    FROM NAMES
    WHERE NAME IN ('name1', 'name2', 'name3')

[Code: 900, SQL State: 42000]  ORA-00900: Ungültige SQL-Anweisung
  [Script position: 188 - 191]  END LOOP

[Code: 900, SQL State: 42000]  ORA-00900: Ungültige SQL-Anweisung
  [Script position: 198 - 202]  END
```

Why Oracle does not recognize `;` symbol which I use at the end of statement? After declare cursor, I want to make a loop over this list and use `name` as a part of insert statement.

I use DBVisualizer Pro 11.

Comment: Put a newline after `DECLARE`. Apart from that your code looks fine.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit New line does not help. I don't even think if that could help since SQL is indentation and newlines insensitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I a found solution, the problem was with `DbVisualizer`.

To execute PL/SQL statements in the DBVisualizer I need to too add `--/` before the first line of code and `/` after the last line of code.

So code should especially looks this:

```sql
--/
DECLARE CURSOR my_data IS
    SELECT ID, NAME
    FROM NAMES
    WHERE NAME IN ('name1', 'name2', 'name3');
BEGIN
  FOR i IN my_data LOOP
         dbms_output.put_line(i.ID);
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Answer (score 1):

You need "more". A PL/SQL block must have a BEGIN-END (where you will work *on* that cursor).  Thus you would typically see something like

```
DECLARE CURSOR my_data IS
    SELECT ID, NAME
    FROM NAMES
    WHERE NAME IN ('name1', 'name2', 'name3');
BEGIN
  for i in my_data loop
     ...
     ...
  end loop;
END;
```

Comment: Hello Connor McDonals, unfortunately it does not work, SQL throws more errors, I have extended my question and added more info about errors during iteration and declaration.

Answer (score 1):

Code you posted is OK:

```
SQL> select * from names;

        ID NAME
---------- ----------
      7782 CLARK
      7839 KING
      7934 MILLER

SQL> SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
SQL> DECLARE
  2     CURSOR my_data IS
  3        SELECT ID, NAME
  4          FROM NAMES
  5         WHERE NAME IN ('CLARK', 'KING', 'MILLER');
  6  BEGIN
  7     FOR i IN my_data
  8     LOOP
  9        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (i.ID);
 10     END LOOP;
 11  END;
 12  /
7782
7839
7934

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

---

Which tool do you use? Is that the **whole** script you ran? Because, some tools don't allow commands to be *adjacent* to each other and require at least one empty line between them.

Comment: I use DBVisualizer Pro 11.0.5 and I run only this script in SQL Commander tab.

Comment: I found solution.. When I want to execute PL/SQL statements in DBVisualizer I need to too  add `--/` at before first line of code and `/` after last line of code. Thank you for tip about tool settings!

Comment: Right; I never used DBVisualizer but Googled for it now and people - who had similar problems - were told to do exactly what you did. I'm glad you fixed it!